# При попытке запостить фотографию она поворачивается

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Вставляю в веб-страницу фотографию книжной ориентации - она поворачивается набок. С фотографиями альбомной ориентации все нормально.

Вопрос: какой параметр необходимо задать в CSS, чтобы повернуть фото? И еще вопрос: почему такое происходит?

p.s Укажу Ruby on Rails, так как работаю в нем, и фотографии, соответственно, с его помощью и загружаю. Вдруг с ним связано

Comment: Скорее всего, потому что она на самом деле повёрнутая, а ваш софт по каким-то причинам показывает её не в первоначальной форме. Для воспроизведения проблемы недостаточно информации.